# Why would my app only see one of two associated files?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

This is a fairly simple app that opens and decodes packed XML. I can open the files directly from the apps UI no problem.
The issue is, I have 2 types associated with my app.
The ICON shows next to the 2 file types as they should, how ever, only one, if double clicked shows up in the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

`Dim arguments() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` seems fool-proof.
I have used a msgbox to trap and display anything in position 1 of the list and the 2nd file type NEVER sends anything to the args list.
I am deploying (for now) using clickOnce and added per what I read at MS's site the following to the manifest file:

```
<fileAssociation
     xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
     extension=".visual"
     description="WoT visual file"
     progid="wotvisual"
     defaultIcon="XMLFile_789_32.ico"
/>
<fileAssociation
     xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1"
     extension=".chunk"
     description="WoT chunk file"
     progid="wotchunk"
     defaultIcon="XMLFile_789_32.ico"
/>
```

This is at the head of my main form load event:

```
    Dim arguments() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        If arguments.Length > 1 Then
        Dim s1 = arguments(1)
        If s1 <> String.Empty Then
            openVisual(s1)
        End If
```

I should mention that dbl clicking either file does indeed open my app.. It just never sees anything as in file path, from the .chunk types.

And if you spotted it, this is World Of Tanks I'm working with. I write tools for the modding community.

Comment: need more data on how your app works

Comment: What does the .visual file put into the command line args?

Comment: The full path to the .visual

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of the two `fileassociation` elements?

Comment: The 2 file types contents are near identical.. so its just a matter of why one   
isnt showing up.

Comment: Humm.. let me find out.. .back in 5 :)

Comment: There is an example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882599.aspx.  You need to make yours look as closely to that one as possible, including putting everything on one line (stranger things have happened).  Notice what the progid's look like?  They have two names, separated by a dot; one name is "Document".

Comment: same results... it opens the .visual fine.. and I get NOTHING from the .chunk types.
Thanks.. let me check that out :)

Comment: can you give a sample on what printing argument() looks like

Comment: Well...Francis, its either the full path to the .visual or its nothing at all.
I tried putting every thing on one like..No luck.

Comment: <fileAssociation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" extension=".chunk" description="WoT chunk file" progid="wot.chunk" defaultIcon="XMLFile_789_32.ico" />
 <fileAssociation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" extension=".visual" description="WoT visual file" progid="wot.visual" defaultIcon="XMLFile_789_32.ico" />

That will look goofy I think

Comment: it means that your .chunk is in position "0" of the array.. you were only sending/using arguments(1) (which is the 2nd position.. based above which contains the .visual file.. try changing it to argument(0).. and see what happens

Comment: Will do.. give me a few minutes

Comment: I get this when opening the .visual...
C:\!_XML_Viewer\WoT_Xml_Editor\bin\Debug\WoT_Xml_Editor.exe
C:\Games\World_of_Tanks\extracted\content\Buildings\bld_101_01_Vhouse01\merged\lod0\bld_101_01_Vhouse01.visual

Comment: YIKES.. I get this junk when I open a .chunk:
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Y8W9P81G.PMH\V1AQRQED.C40\wot_..tion_70f39e5cb5a4d0b6_0001.0000_7114779e665884a8\WoT_Xml_Editor.exe

Comment: i see an issue.. the .visual looks to be bound to the debug version?? the other.. not sure what its doing lol

Comment: im not really familiar with editors or what opens what.. but does the .visual have the same editor as the .chunk?.. do you have like an openChunk(s1) function there?.. or thats it?.. it seems to me that your app is only limited/supports to opening the .visual file

Comment: They are the same format.. just different names because of what they are used for in the creation of the game at startup and level loadiing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82881/discussion-between-francis-fuerte-and-mike-o).

Comment: I have to figure out how to unbind the association of the.visual.. So far it keeps rebinding to the debug location. Even when I manually set in in its properties to open with notepad.. it reverts to my debug app.
OK.. had to uninstall my app first.. Odd when its not bound to that location

Comment: did it fix your problem?

Comment: Nope.. Thanks guys.. I think I have more going on here .. I can't Install now.. Says its already install tho I uninstalled using the programs and features.. Registry must be fubar.. that would explain some of the binding issues too.

Comment: could be a deeper problem.. or just a simple one that didn't catch your attention.. explore and you shall find ;)

Comment: I gave up.. threw in the towel.. ate the last donut.. and created a setup project. For all the reading.. all the hair pulling and head banging on the keyboard and 20+ hrs of try this.. try that... NOTHING solved the problem.
Word to the wise.. Dont even mess with trying to get this working in windows 7 with a clickonce app unless you have very good voodoo magic powers. This is a very VERY common issue and people are trying to solve this all over the world.
Thanks for the input and taking a stab at the problem :)